# installing jdk/sbt on new ubuntu machine

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, sbt

I'm trying to install SBT on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 machine on AWS.  I've never had a problem installing (following instructions) before, but I am now.

I get this error...  "***The java installation you have is not up to date
requires at least version 1.6+, you have version 1.8***"

Seems confusing, since 1.8 seems to satisfy the 1.6+ requirement.

references

scala - https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started-sbt-track/getting-started-with-scala-and-sbt-on-the-command-line.html

sbt - http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

```
sudo apt-get update 

java -version
# The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
#  * default-jre
#  * gcj-5-jre-headless
#  * openjdk-8-jre-headless
#  * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
#  * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
#  * openjdk-9-jre-headless
# Try: sudo apt install <selected package>

sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk -y

java -version
# openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
# OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt

sbt
# /usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash: line 207: bc: command not found

# The java installation you have is not up to date
# requires at least version 1.6+, you have
# version 1.8

# Please go to http://www.java.com/getjava/ and download
# a valid Java Runtime and install before running .
```

Comment: I don't know anything about SBT, but it looks like it's complaining about missing the `bc` command: "bc: command not found". It might just be a wrong assumption by the script logic that the failure is due to java version.

Comment: thanks @mjb2kmn ...  searching for that instead of java version stuff turned up this...  https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/issues/192

Comment: Well, there you go, nice find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source of the setup, it is using `bc` to do the arithmetic check on the java version number and is unable to run `bc`.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/320d993fa6a9ad857b65d4cafca6ea9e5d1550b3/src/universal/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash#L207

You can install `bc` with `apt install bc`.

Comment: page not found for link.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I've updated the link to a historical commit accurate for the day this was answered.